# Good software to monitor disk io, memory and cpu use?

Tags: linux, monitoring, profiling

I'm developing a website. I was wondering if there are any tools out there that make it easy to log and graph usage statistics of how my cpu, memory, disk and network are used.

I need to somehow know when I need to scale up / when I'm going to get problems soon.

I found http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/
(command line thingy, not so useful because I'd have to write my own graphics and logging layer on top of it..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/).

Answer (score 1):

[GKrellm](http://members.dslextreme.com/users/billw/gkrellm/gkrellm.html).

> GKrellM is a single process stack of system monitors which supports
>   applying themes to match its appearance to your window manager, Gtk,
>   or any other theme.

Comment: +1 because I've been using that since I started using Linux in 2004 and it's still awesome.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't quite happy with the way RRDT-based tools work, you may want to try Zabbix.

CPU, memory, disk and network are in the default template for all OSes, so it should be relatively configuration free. You can get Zabbix packages (both server and client) with many Linux distributions' package management system directly.

It uses more traditional databases like MySQL, so it does consume more resources than RRDT.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SeaLion](https://sealion.com) it's free. Works great for multiple servers and is pretty lightweight for you to use for a single server even. Setup is pretty simple and shows all of what you ask in a simple timeline for easy debugging. You just have to schedule your own commands and output of those will be monitored every interval specified.

[Watch a 1 minute SeaLion video](https://www.youtube.com/embed/fLqVQd1SMmY?autoplay=1&rel=0&vq=hd720)

[image]